# Agents moving along a gradient

Tags: gradient, netlogo

I want to create a situation where the turtles check their previous patch with the patch they just moved to, if the new patch has a higher c value then the turtle will use the new_p1 in its calculation to switch between status 0 or 1 (this is modelling tumbling and running of e coli). After deciding to stay running (0) or switch to tumbling (1) it should update it's oldc value in order to make its decision for further moves. The turtles are also assigned either 0 or 1 status on spawn based on a calculation of equilibrium. My issue is that running the program I do not see the turtles accumulating on the right as they are supposed to (I've created a gradient along each patch where the further right the higher c value the patch has)

```
ask turtles [                     
if (status = 0)
[
fd 0.3                         
set heading heading + 10 * (2 * random-float 1.0 - 1.0)    
set rsq xcor * xcor + ycor * ycor                            
set msq msq + rsq                                             
ifelse (c > oldc)
  [if ( random-float 100 < new_p1 ) [set status 1]][if ( random-float 100 < p1 ) [set status 1]]
set oldc c
]
fd 0.02                         
set heading heading + 180 * (2 * random-float 1.0 - 1.0)    
set rsq xcor * xcor + ycor * ycor                             
set msq msq + rsq
if ( random-float 100 < p2 ) [set status 0]
set oldc c
```

]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem, in this case I should be using an ifelse instead of an if as it allows the tumble procedure to proceed after the run procedure has been run

```
ask turtles [                     
ifelse (status = 0)
[
fd 0.3                         
set heading heading + 10 * (2 * random-float 1.0 - 1.0)    
set rsq xcor * xcor + ycor * ycor                            
set msq msq + rsq                                             
ifelse (c > oldc)
  [if ( random-float 100 < new_p1 ) [set status 1]][if ( random-float 100 < p1 ) [set status 1]]
set oldc c
]
[
fd 0.02                         
set heading heading + 180 * (2 * random-float 1.0 - 1.0)    
set rsq xcor * xcor + ycor * ycor                             
set msq msq + rsq
if ( random-float 100 < p2 ) [set status 0]
set oldc c
]
```